# Store environment variables within declared environment variable, Jenkins Pipeline 2.0

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, environment

This code is giving me error in jenkins

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Metrics for class: java.lang.String

```
def init_metrics(){
    env.previousStageEnd = 0
    env.stageDuration
    env.stageTimes = [:]
}
init_metrics()

node{
    stage('Metrics'){
        println " - " + env.previousStageEnd + " - " + env.stageTimes + " - " + env.stageDuration + " - " + env.STAGE_NAME
        env.stageTimes[env.STAGE_NAME] = currentBuild.duration - (env.previousStageEnd as int)
        previousStageEnd = currentBuild.duration
    }
}
```

the problem with this guy here `env.stageTimes[env.STAGE_NAME]` for some reasons I can't add environment `stage_name` in another environment declared by me. it works only if those variables are not environment but local.

Comment: Try passing that environment variable as a string, that should solve the problem, I've faced it as well a while ago.

Comment: String stage_name = env.STAGE_NAME
        env.stageTimes[stage_name] = currentBuild.duration - (env.previousStageEnd as int)     - it is same issue

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself, what I mean is, take the env variable as a string like that `"${env.STAGE_NAME}"`

Comment: Hello Shlomi Bazel, thank you for suggestion, but it is still doesn't want to work env.stageTimes["${env.STAGE_NAME}"] 
        .groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Metrics for class: java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

solution to this would be to define environment = []

```
def init_metrics(){
    environment = [
        previousStageEnd = 0,
        stageDuration = null,
        stageTimes = [:]
    ]
}
init_metrics()

node{
    stage('Metrics'){
        println " - " + env.previousStageEnd + " - " + env.stageTimes + " - " + env.stageDuration + " - " + env.STAGE_NAME
        env.stageTimes[env.STAGE_NAME] = currentBuild.duration - (env.previousStageEnd as int)
        previousStageEnd = currentBuild.duration
    }
}
```